# How to export to NetCDF format

Tags: export, bugs, data

Consider I have a scalar field on a grid `f(x,y)`, where `x` and `y` can take values

```
x={1,2}
y={1,2,3}
```

so the grid points are

```
{{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{2,1},{2,2},{2,3}}
```

and the value of `f` on these grid points are

```
f={1,2,3,2,4,6}
```

How can I export this into a NetCDF file that has a structure similar to

```
netcdf foo {

     dimensions:
       x = 2, y = 3;

     variables:
       int x(x), y(y);
       int f(x,y);
     data:
       x   = 1,2;
       y   = 1,2,3;
       f   = 1,2,3,2,4,6;
     }
```

I tried to follow the examples in the [NetCDF format documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/NetCDF.html) page, but not able to make it work.

For example, if we try

```
path = Export["test.nc", {"x" -> x, "y" -> y, "f" -> f}];
Import["!ncdump " <> path, "Text"]
```

The exported NetCDF file looks like:

```
netcdf test {
dimensions:
    xDim1 = 2 ;
    yDim1 = 3 ;
    fDim1 = 6 ;
variables:
    int x(xDim1) ;
    int y(yDim1) ;
    int f(fDim1) ;
data:

 x = 1, 2 ;
 y = 1, 2, 3 ;
 f = 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6 ;
}
```

We can see that Mathematica exports all three variables independently, rather than keep `f` as a dependent variable on `x` and `y`. The dependence of the variables will be very important because it reflects the structure of the data.

So how can I export the data correctly so that it generate the linked variables, as in the first example?

Note that the NetCDF file can be viewed using [ncdump](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf_utilities_guide.html#guide_ncdump).

---

**update**

Confirmed by Wolfram Technical Support as a bug.

Comment: I wonder, should your definition of the $y$ range in the second to last line be `y = 1, 2, 3` in keeping with your example? Could you explain where the 10 comes from otherwise?

Comment: @MarcoB Good catch! I correct that typo. Thanks.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it didn't address the dependence of the dimensions of `f` on those of `x` and `y`. Perhaps you should make this requirement more explicit in your question.

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar Thanks! I made the question more clearly now.

Answer (score 2):

In WL 13.1+:

```
In[1]:= Export["foo.nc", {
  "Dimensions" -> {
    "x" -> {1, 2},
    "y" -> {1, 2, 3}
  },
  "Datasets" -> 
    "f" -> {
      "Data" -> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}},
      "DimensionNames" -> {"x", "y"}
    }
  }, "Rules"]

Out[5]= "foo.nc"
```

gives the desired file structure:

```
➜  ~ ncdump foo.nc   
netcdf foo {
dimensions:
    x = 2 ;
    y = 3 ;
variables:
    int64 x(x) ;
    int64 y(y) ;
    int64 f(x, y) ;
data:

 x = 1, 2 ;

 y = 1, 2, 3 ;

 f =
  1, 2, 3,
  4, 5, 6 ;
}
```